# How to mask input "(500)-000-0000" with ngx-mask?

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

I am using [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) in my project. Normally I defined my phone number's mask like this: "(000)-000-0000)". But I am wondering how can I do it like this: "(500)-000-0000)"? When I try it, it breaks my code.

Comment: Ngx mask describes the pattern of the input, not the value itself.  Do you want  the number prefix starting with 5?

Comment: We can say that. I know I can use prefix, but don't know how.